# Onde ficam armazenados os elementos que o LINQ seleciona?

Tags: c#, linq

Estou estudando LINQ agora e me bateu uma dúvida: Um LINQ que é executado sem os métodos `ToList()` ou `ToArray()` retorna um `IEnumerable<>`, certo?

Mas um `IEnumerable<>` não é exatamente uma lista/*array*, ou é?
( Que eu saiba ele é apenas uma *interface* que retorna um `IEnumerator` para o `Iterator` e que ele está em todas as listas, mas isso já é outro tópico... )
Já que uma *interface* obviamente não pode ser instanciada, onde então fica armazenado os elementos que o LINQ seleciona? Ele faz polimorfismo e instancia uma `List`?
Exemplo:

```
int[] numeros = new int[] { 0, 3, 10, 7, 14 };

// Na linha abaixo é aplicado polimorfismo e é criado uma lista?
// IEnumerable<int> numerosPares = new List<int>(); ?
IEnumerable<int> numerosPares = from n in numeros where (n % 2) == 0 select n;
foreach(int numero in numerosPares){
    Console.WriteLine(numero);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Já que uma interface obviamente não pode ser instanciada, onde então fica armazenado os elementos que o LINQ seleciona? Ele faz polimorfismo e instancia uma `List`?

Os métodos do namespace LINQ retornam implementações privadas da interface `IEnumerable<T>`.
Por exemplo, o método `Select<T>` ([implementacao aqui](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,5c652c53e80df013,references)) retorna uma instância da classe privada [`WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8bf16962931637d3,references).

O `OrderBy` retorna uma instância da classe [`OrderedEnumerable`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/2d89a8f513559ba0.html)

> Onde ficam armazenados os elementos que o LINQ seleciona?

Quanto a armazenamento - não existe. As instâncias de `IEnumerable<T>` criadas usando LINQ sao *monads* - um conceito *muito* usado em programação funcional. Neste caso, a monad `IEnumerable<T>` não  representa a colecção - representa uma computação, um código, que quando executado irá retornar uma série de elementos.

[Da wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29):

> In functional programming, a monad is a structure that represents computations defined as sequences of steps: a type with a monad structure defines what it means to chain operations, or nest functions of that type together.

Em termos de estado, esta monad apenas contém o código necessário para transformar a colecção original noutra, e um apontador para a colecção original.

Answer (score 1):

Não ficam armazenados porque ainda não existem.

Quando escreve

```
IEnumerable<int> numerosPares = from n in numeros where (n % 2) == 0 select n;
```

Tente pensar nos seguintes termos

```
Query[IEnumerable<int>] numerosPares = from n in numeros where (n % 2) == 0 select n;
```

O que esta a fazer e **criar uma `query`**. Esta `query` **não e executada** ate que a utilize.

Para forcar a execução da `query`, e como disse, pode usar os métodos `ToList()` ou `ToArray()` (e nesse momento os resultados são trazidos para memoria de uma só vez).

Por outro lado, quando utiliza a `query` num bloco `foreach(...)`, esta a executa-la e a percorrer cada elemento do resultado um a um.

Isto e uma das razoes, por exemplo, que o ReSharper alerta para o uso múltiplo da mesma `query`. Se a fonte de dados mudar entre execuções da `query`, o resultado final ira mudar.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>(){2,4,6};
IEnumerable<int> numerosPares = from n in numeros where (n % 2) == 0 select n;
Console.WriteLine("Primeira execucao");
foreach(var n in numerosPares)
{
     Console.WriteLine(n); // Output 2,4,6
}
numeros.AddRange(new int[]{8,10,12});

Console.WriteLine("\nSegunda execucao");
foreach(var n in numerosPares)
{
     Console.WriteLine(n); // Output 2,4,6,8,10,12
}
```

(Código disponível no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySWFs4))

Como pode ver, a lista que serve de fonte muda entre as execuções e os números imprimidos mudam também.

**Neste momento, em memoria apenas existe a lista `numeros`.**

Assim, se quiser que o resultado seja final (i.e, não mude entre execuções):

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>(){2,4,6};
IEnumerable<int> numerosPares = (from n in numeros where (n % 2) == 0 select n).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Primeira execucao");
foreach(var n in numerosPares)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n); // Output 2,4,6
}
numeros.AddRange(new int[]{8,10,12});

Console.WriteLine("\nSegunda execucao");
foreach(var n in numerosPares)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n); // Output 2,4,6
}
```

(Código disponível no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OUwJ4z))

Neste exemplo, a lista que serve de fonte muda entre as execuções mas a `query` já foi executada, ou seja os números impressos já não vão mudar mesmo que a fonte de dados mude.

**Neste momento, em memoria existem duas listas: `numeros` e `numerosPares`.**

Answer (score 1):

Você fez uma pequena confusão. 
Quando se diz que uma interface não pode ser instanciada, não significa que ela não pode ter uma instância. Ela não pode ser instanciada diretamente. Quem vai criar essa instância é um construtor de uma classe que implementa a interface.

Ex:

```
public interface INomeavel
{
    string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Produto : INomeavel
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
}

public class Local : INomeavel
{ 
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
}
```

Nesse caso:

```
INomeavel produto1 = new Produto();
INomeavel local1 = new Local();
```

Quem mantém os valores de `Nome` para `produto1` e `local1`? A própria instância de cada uma das implementações. Ao fazer o cast para o tipo genérico `INomeavel`, você acaba perdendo o acesso aos outros membros além dos membros da interface. Porém esses membros não foram destruídos e ainda podem ser acessados fazendo o cast de volta para o tipo mais específico.

Enfim, quando isso é útil? No exemplo da sua própria pergunta. Pense na interface como uma forma de dizer que um tipo ou um grupo de tipos (aqueles que implementam a interface) terão PELO MENOS aqueles membros definidos pela interface.

Portanto, onde ficam os elementos que o LINQ seleciona? Na instância de qualquer classe que implementa `IEnumerable`.